# Why is /etc/mysql/my.cnf showing permission denied

Tags: mysql

I am trying to edit the `my.cnf` file to allow remote access and ultimately using software from my Windows Server to configure scheduled backup for MySQL Server. So I am using `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` command, it returns with permission denied. Can you tell me why?

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is not a command; it's a file.

Comment: Use a text editor like vi,vim or nano to edit the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Also use `sudo` if you are using a sudo user to perform the action

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error:

```
bash: /etc/mysql/my.cnf: Permission denied
```

because you don't have permissions to edit this file which is a symbolic link to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback`. Editing symbolic links is not permitted, so you need to edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback` instead in nano text editor using this command:

```
sudoedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback`. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.